# hdfs -count: Illegal option -v

Tags: hadoop, command-line, hdfs, bigdata

I was trying to get header but it say Illegal option -v

```
hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v hdfs_path
-count: Illegal option -v
```

Hadoop version: Hadoop 2.6.0.3.0.0.0-249

Source link: [hdfs count](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count)

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Versions matter.

The documentation on your link is related to hadoop 2.7. It seems the option -v didn't exist in Hadoop 2.6

This is the documentation for hadoop 2.6: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count